# Writing SQL with COUNT expression in Kohana

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

I have 2 tables:

incident (id, incident_description)
comment (id, incident_id, comment_description)

I want to write such SQL expression:

```
SELECT incident.*, COUNT(comment.id) AS com 
FROM incident 
LEFT JOIN comment ON comment.incident_id=incident.id 
GROUP BY incident.id 
ORDER BY com DESC
```

it works fine in phpmyadmin.

I write in in ORM:

```
ORM::factory('incident')
->select('incident.*',array('COUNT("comment.id")', 'com'))
->join('comment', 'LEFT')
->on('comment.incident_id', '=', 'incident.id')
->group_by('incident.id')
->order_by('com', 'DESC')
->find_all();
```

but I got an error:
**system/libraries/Database.php [296]:**
**trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given**

code from Database.php:

```
 foreach ($sql as $val)
                {
                        if (($val = trim($val)) === '') continue;

                        if (strpos($val, '(') === FALSE AND $val !== '*')
                        {
                                if (preg_match('/^DISTINCT\s++(.+)$/i', $val, $matches))
                                {
                                        $val            = $this->config['table_prefix'].$matches[1];
                                        $this->distinct = TRUE;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                        $val = (strpos($val, '.') !== FALSE) ? $this->config['table_prefix'].$val : $val;
                                }

                                $val = $this->driver->escape_column($val);
                        }

                        $this->select[] = $val;
                }
```

Comment: What about special column `comment_count` for `incident` table? You can increment it with event (comment added/deleted) instead of counting every time.

Answer (score 4):

`array(DB::expr('COUNT("comment.id")'), 'com')`

You don't want the Query Builder to try and escape complex expression or other database functions. In these cases, you will need to use a database expression created with [DB::expr](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/DB#expr).

Comment: This could use a little explanation to clarify which part of the faulty line was being interpreted as an array.

Answer (score -1):

For Kohana 2 you want something like this

```
ORM::factory('incident')
->select('incident.*','COUNT("comment.id") AS comments')
->join('comment', 'comment.incident_id', 'incident.id', 'LEFT')
->groupby('incident.id')
->orderby('comments', 'DESC')
->find_all();
```

Or using DB query

```
DB::instance()->query('SELECT incident.*, COUNT(comment.id) AS comments 
FROM incident 
LEFT JOIN comment ON comment.incident_id = incident.id 
GROUP BY incident.id 
ORDER BY comments DESC');
```